# How to find the shortest boundary to boundary distance for all objects with boundary points?

Tags: c++, algorithm, nearest-neighbor, intel-ipp

Hi Guys Actually i have "N" different objects in a 2D Plane and For all those objects i have their boundary points also. As shown in image
[image: here Look at this image for clear idea]

i want to find the shortest boundary to boundary distance for all objects as shown [image: here]

eg.for object 1 shown in image it will be d1.
like this for all other objects too.
I know one possible way that is by Brut Force but i am looking for good performance .Please let me know if you are aware of any existing algorithm which can do this in optimized way.thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Quick tip: people tend to answer your question more quickly when you add code or images to your post.

Comment: Do you have to find the shortest distance between ALL objects? For example, in the given figure, should the algorithm also find the shortest distance between object 2 and 5?

Comment: @lucieon hi ! no algorithm will return only one distance for each object .For example. For oject 1 it returns d1 , for Object 2  some value (nearest boundary distance) and so on